# NodeList.SelectSingleNode() syntax

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces, selectsinglenode

Having problems getting NodeList.SelectSingleNode() to work properly.
My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<inm:Results xmlns:inm="http://www.namespace.com/1.0">
    <inm:Recordset setCount="18254">
        <inm:Record setEntry="0">
            <!-- snip -->
            <inm:Image>fileName.jpg</inm:Image>
        </inm:Record>
    </inm:Recordset>
</inm:Results>
```

The data is a long series of `<inm:Record>` entries.

I open the doc and get create a NodeList object based on "inm:Record".  This works great.

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName);
XmlNodeList xRecord = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("inm:Record");
```

I start looping through the NodeList using a for loop.  Before I process a given entry, I want to check and see if the `<inm:Image>` is set.  I thought it would be super easy just to do

```
string strImage = xRecord[i].SelectSingleNode("inm:Image").InnerText;
```

My thinking being, "For the XRecord that I'm on, go find the `<inm:Image>` value ...But this doesn't work as I get the exception saying that I need a XmlNameSpaceManager.  So, I tried to set that up but could never get the syntax right.

Can someone show me how to use the correct XmlNameSpaceManager syntax in this case.

I've worked around the issue for now by looping through all of the childNodes for a given xRecord, and checking the  tag once I loop around to it.  I would like to check that  value first to see if I need to loop over that `<inm:Record>` entry at all.

Comment: I generally find the newer `System.Xml.Linq` libraries to be much easier to extract and manipulate XML data quickly, particularly with the XName class which simplifies dealing with per-element namespaces.

Comment: Please see "[Stack Overflow does not allow tags in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to loop through all the Record elements, just use XPath to specify the subset that you want:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName);
XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("inm", "http://www.inmagic.com/webpublisher/query");
XmlNodeList nodes = xdoc.SelectNodes("/inm:Results/inm:Recordset/inm:Record[inm:Image != '']", manager);
```

Comment: So this is analogous to a SELECT where <inm:Image> is not empty?  Cool.  So I go ahead and filter out the records that don't require processing in the first step.  Nice.

Comment: Exactly.  It returns a list of the Record elements that have an image.  If however, you wanted a list of the Image elements themselves, you could simply select "/inm:Results/inm:Recordset/inm:Record/inm:Image".  That would still only return the ones that have an image element, but it would be giving you the image elements rather than the Record elements.

Comment: LINQ, as others have suggested can be very useful, and it has some extra compile-time error checking, which is nice.  But in my opinion, sometimes it can get really ugly where a simple XPath query does the trick.  XPath is an industry standard which is useful to know for other reasons, such as XSLT, whereas LINQ is a proprietary MS technology.  Again, nothing against LINQ.  It's definitely a good option.  I just don't like people disparaging XPath just because LINQ is "newer".

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
string strImage = xRecord[i].SelectSingleNode("inm:Image",nsMgr).InnerText;
```

Should do it.

Comment: Thanks guys.  The above results in an XPathException "Namespace prefix 'inm' is not defined."

Answer (score 0):

Using the [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688087.aspx) libraries, here's an example for retrieving that said node's value:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName);
List<XElement> docElements = doc.Elements().ToList();
XElement results = docElements.Elements().Where(
   ele => ele.Name.LocalName == "Results").First();
XElement firstRecord = results.Elements().Where(
   ele => ele.Name.LocalName == "Record").First();
XElement recordImage = firstRecord .Elements().Where(
   ele => ele.Name.LocalName == "Image").First();
string imageName = recordImage.Value;
```

Also, by the way, using [Hungarian notation for a type-checked language is overkill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation#Disadvantages). You don't need to prepend string variables with `str` when it will always be a `string`.

Comment: Mike, thanks for the response.  At age 45, I've been naming variables so long, I don't think I could code without str, etc... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using this [Xml library](https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/), you can get all the records that have an Image child element with this:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName);
XElement[] records = root.XPath("//Record[Image]").ToArray();
```

If you want to be sure that the Image child contains a value, it can be expressed like this:

```
XElement[] records = root.XPath("//Record[Image != '']").ToArray();
```

Comment: Why ToArray() when you can just manipulate the returned List<XElement>?